# How to parse a string to a React component?

Tags: reactjs

Say I have a string `const s = "I love $FB"`, and I wanna get:

`<p>I love <a href="/symbol/FB">$FB</a></p>` by `<RenderContent content={s}>`

I can use reg to extract the symbol, but how can I turn the string into a React component, without using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`?

Comment: I suppose a good option here is to use React.createElement in your RenderContent component, see all about using react without JSX here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-jsx.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative render function for a component to use regex capturing groups, no validation is done on the .exec result however:

```
render() {
  const subs = /(^.*)(\$(.*))/.exec(this.props.content);
  return (
    <p>
      { subs[1] }
      <a href={`/symbol/${subs[3]}`}>{subs[2]}</a>
    </p>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your render method you can do this:

```
<p>{this.props.s.split('$')[0]} 

 <a href="/symbol/{this.props.s.split('$')[1]}">${this.props.s.split('$')[1]}
 </a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
ReactDOM.render(<RenderContent><p>I love <a href="/symbol/FB">$FB</a></p></RenderContent>, element);
```

Now in your RenderContent Component use the following code:

```
render(){
   return <div>{this.props.children}</div> //this will render your inner react component

}
```